# Is there any possibilities that the following partial sum of the Dirichlet eta function can be zero?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

If we accept--  $s_o$ --  as one of the non-trivial  zeros of the Riemann zeta function  by $0 <Re(s_o)<1$   and     $Re(s_o)$ is the real part of a complex variable, we know:

$$\eta(s_o ) = \sum_{1}^\infty \frac {(-1)^{n-1}} {n^{s_o}}=0 \tag{1}$$

Now, can we show that the following partial sum can not be zero?

$N$: Sufficiently large integer

$$\left|\sum_{1}^N \frac {(-1)^{n-1}} {n^{s_o}}\right|≠0 \tag{2}$$

Or can we show that the remainder term can not be zero?

$$\left|\sum_{N+1}^\infty \frac {(-1)^{n-1}} {n^{s_o}}\right|≠0 \tag{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{eqnarray} f_s(t) = t^{-s}, f_s'(t) &=&-s t^{-s-1}, f_s''(t) = s(s+1)t^{-s-2} \\
 f_s(n)-f_s(n+1) &=& -f_s'(n)+O(f_s''(n)) = s n^{-s-1} +O(s(s+1) n^{-s-2})\\
\sum_{n=N}^\infty (2n)^{-s}-(2n+1)^{-s} &=& \sum_{n=N}^\infty s (2n)^{-s-1} +O(s(s+1) (2n)^{-s-2}) \\ &=&s(s+1) 2^{-s-1}\sum_{n=N}^\infty \int_N^\infty x^{-s-2}dx+O(\frac{s(s+1)}{\Re(s+1)} (2N)^{-s-1}) \\ &=& s(s+1) 2^{-s-1} \int_N^\infty \lfloor x-N \rfloor x^{-s-2}dx + O(\frac{s(s+1)}{\Re(s+1)} (2N)^{-s-1}) \\
& =& s(s+1) 2^{-s-1} \int_N^\infty ( x-N +O(1)) x^{-s-2}dx + O(\frac{s(s+1)}{\Re(s+1)} (2N)^{-s-1})
\\ &=& s(s+1) 2^{-s-1} (\frac{N^{-s}}{s} - N\frac{N^{-s-1}}{s+1}+O(\frac{N^{-s-1}}{\Re(s+1)})) +O(\frac{s(s+1)}{\Re(s+1)} (2N)^{-s-1})\end{eqnarray}$$

which is non-zero for $N \ge N(s)$ large enough.

Comment: But $s$ can be complex.

Comment: @Szeto in my post $s$ is complex $\Re(s) >0$. where do you see assuming it is real

Comment: Dear Reuns., Thank you for your kind answer .

Comment: @Testform Do you think the $O$ constants are all $1$ ? If so what $N(s)$ does it give ?

Comment: @Szeto , reality your proof  does not look very clear. Can you try with another way?  And you have not noticed the non-trivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function. What do you think ?

Comment: @Testform I did not provide a proof.

Comment: @Testform What is unclear to you

Comment: @Szeto that you didn't delete your comment means that you are not convinced yet ?

Comment: @Szeto pardon ı wrote to you by mistake.

Comment: @ reuns,   I mean, can we say now that the equation in (3) is correct with one of the non-trivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function?  You did not stated it.  Also how you can  re-arrange the equations in your line 3.  Because, as you know that  it is not absolute convergent by $0 <Re(s_o)<1$  .

Comment: @Testform ?? Don't you see that $\sum_{n=N}^\infty (2n)^{-s} - (2n+1)^{-s}=\sum_{n = 2N}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} n^{-s}$ is the tail of the series for $\eta(s)$ ? $\sum_{n=N}^\infty |(2n)^{-s} - (2n+1)^{-s}|$ does converge for $\Re(s) > 0$, not the same as $\sum_{n=N}^\infty |(2n)^{-s} |+ |(2n+1)^{-s}|$. Of course if you want to start at $2N-1$ instead of $2N$ it doesn't change it much. That $\eta(s) = 0$ or $\eta(s) \ne 0$ doesn't change anything for the tail.

Comment: @reuns, thank you. That is okey.  Only I could not understand that how you can say the following is non-zero:   $s(s+1) 2^{-s-1} (\frac{N^{-s}}{s} - N\frac{N^{-s-1}}{s+1}+O(\frac{N^{-s-1}}{\Re(s+1)})) +O(\frac{s(s+1)}{\Re(s+1)} (2N)^{-s-1})$         which is non-zero for $N \ge N(s)$ large enough.

Comment: @reuns, you wrote "which is non-zero for $N \ge N(s)$ large enough"  in your answer.  What  is  $N(s)$ here ?

Comment: @Testform Do you understand the Big-O notation ? In my answer the O constants don't depend on $s$, so once you know $C$ the uniform O constant then $N(s)$ is any function $s \to [1,\infty)$ such that $\frac{1}{s(s+1)}+\frac{z / N(s)}{\Re(s+1)} \ne 0$ for $|z| < C$. That's why my first comment was if you can find a valid $C$.

Comment: @reuns ,  again me. Now I get only here :  You say:   the following  one will be  non-zero ,    $$\frac{N^{-s}}{s(s+1)}+O(\frac{N^{-s-1}}{\Re(s+1)})) +O(\frac{s(s+1)}{\Re(s+1)} (2N)^{-s-1}$$    When ?   For all sufficiently large $N$ numbers ?   Please make your study/comment here **a little more simple way** for me.   I mean after here , can you go a  little more further by showing everything  as  every body can understand your work here .Thank you.

Comment: @Testform The big-O notation in the last part of my answer means that for every $s,\Re(s) > 0$ and $N\ge 1$ : $$-\sum_{n=2N}^\infty (-1)^{N+1} n^{-s} =\sum_{n=N}^\infty (2n)^{-s}-(2n+1)^{-s} = s(s+1)( \frac{N^{-s}}{s} - N\frac{N^{-s-1}}{s+1}+u_N(s) + v_N(s))$$ where $|u_N(s)| \le C|\frac{N^{-s-1}}{\Re(s+1)}|, |v_N(s)| \le D |\frac{s(s+1)}{\Re(s+1)} (2N)^{-s-1}|$. I did it such that you can take $C=D=1$. Thus for $N > N(s) = |s(s+1)|\frac{1+|s(s+1)|}{\Re(s+1)}$  the LHS is non-zero. As you see it is not easier to give the details : that's why everybody use the O-notation.

Answer (score 0):

**Can we show it as below for sufficiently large $N$ numbers?**  *(We mean here if we speak about "the neighborhood of  infinity" here; it  is a subset of the set of real numbers which contains an interval ($M,+∞)$. It means this subset contains all sufficiently large  $N$ numbers here as $N>M$).*

Now let write the remainder term  by accepting $´N´$ as even number here:

$$R_{N}(s) =\frac {1} {(N+1)^{s}}-\frac {1} {(N+2)^{s}} + \frac {1} {(N+3)^{s}}- \frac {1} {(N+4)^{s}}+⋅⋅⋅$$

Now, let us think two new functions as completely independent from the above-reminder term (it means they have no any connection with  $R_{N}(s)$ )

$$P_{1}(s) =\frac {1} {(N)^{s}}-\frac {1} {(N+1)^{s}}+\frac {1} {(N+2)^{s}} - \frac {1} {(N+3)^{s}}+⋅⋅⋅$$

$$P_{2}(s) =\frac {1} {(N+2)^{s}}-\frac {1} {(N+3)^{s}}+\frac {1} {(N+4)^{s}} - \frac {1} {(N+5)^{s}}+⋅⋅⋅$$

If we handle them with $R_{N}(s)$ one by one:

$$R_{N}(s)+ P_{1}(s)=\frac {1} {N^{s}} \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\ and \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\ R_{N}(s)+ P_{2}(s)=\frac {1} {(N+1)^{s}}   $$

Then let us consider a  $´c´$  value as $c∈ℝ$  and  $c≥1$. Thus, we can say that there exists a  $´c´$  value, thus we can write the following conditions with all sufficiently large ´$N´$ numbers :

$$ |\frac {1} {c(N+1)^{s}}|<|2R_{N}(s)|<|\frac {c} {N^{s}}|$$

Thus, we conclude with sufficiently large ´N´ numbers at the neighborhood of infinity:

$$|R_N(s)| ≠0$$

But of course, we know $\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} R_{N}(s)=0$.

Comment: @reuns , could you give your valuable comment for the above my work. Do you think " it is acceptable".  Thank you.

Comment: @reuns , good  morning, will I take your valuable comment ?  It is important for me.