# The remainder term of the Riemann zeta function

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

For all $0 <Re(s)$  and  $s≠1$  with  $s=σ+it$  and  $1≤N$

$Re(s)$ is the real part of a complex variable, we know:

$$\zeta(s ) = \sum_{1}^N \frac {1} {n^{s}}-\frac {N^{1-s}} {1-s} \tag{1}+r_N(s)$$

$$r_N(s)=-s\int_{N}^{\infty}{\frac{u-\lfloor u \rfloor}{u^{s+1}}du}$$

And an author showed for the remainder term on http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~mdc/MATH31022/2010-11/notes/Notes4Step4.pdf 
 as:

$$|r_N(s)| ≤ \frac {|s|} {σN^{σ}}$$

QUESTION: If we accept-  $s_o$ -  as one of the non-trivial  zeros of the Riemann zeta function  by $0 <Re(s_o)<1$   and  with  $s_o=σ_o+it_o$ , can we write?

$$|r_N(s_o)| ≠0$$

Comment: The answer is exactly the same as to your previous question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3107193/is-there-any-possibilities-that-the-following-partial-sum-of-the-dirichlet-eta-f/3108005?noredirect=1#comment6425240_3108005 Where are you stuck as seing why. Also I made clear the properties of the tail don't depend on if $\zeta(s_0) = 0$ or not.

Comment: @reuns, thank you. Just after the stage which the author has come above, I want to see that we can go on a little more or not. As you see that his result looks very simple/nice.

Comment: And, where are you stuck ?

Comment: @reuns, thank you. You are really great person for your supporting and patient. Could you possible for you to show here  a similar proof ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show that $$r_N(s) = \sum_{n=N}^\infty \int_n^{n+1} ((n+1)^{-s}-x^{-s})dx$$ If so then what do you get from $$(n+1)^{-s}-x^{-s} =(n+1-x) sn^{-s-1}+O(s(s+1)n^{-s-2})$$
and $$\sum_{n=N}^\infty n^{-s-1} = \sum_{n=N}^\infty (s+1) \int_n^\infty t^{-s-2}dt = (s+1) \int_N^\infty\lfloor t -N+1\rfloor t^{-s-2}dt$$

Comment: thank you. You did it again.  However again, I (myself) can not  see .. $|r_N(s_o)| ≠0$ ..from your study. Could you  try to show it by  a little simple. I mean can you show .. $|r_N(s_o)| ≠0$ ..

Comment: Copying exactly the same development as in the previous answer won't help you... Where are you stuck

Comment: yes, I have sensed it. Could you go a little further here  as like before, please ?